# How are you supposed to use a ShapeDrawable with a PathShape to draw a line on a custom View?

Tags: android, path, line, custom-view, shapedrawable

I am attempting to draw a line in a custom `View`. Here I've created a simple `Path` with just a single segment, created a `PathShape` from that, and finally stuck that into a `ShapeDrawable` with the intention of using that to draw on the `Canvas` inside `onDraw()`. However, this does not work. See my example, here.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.PathShape;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class TestView extends View {

    private Path mPath = null;
    private Paint mPaint = null;
    private PathShape mPathShape = null;
    private ShapeDrawable mShapeDrawable = null;

    public TestView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    private void init() {
        int width = this.getWidth() / 2;
        int height = this.getHeight() / 2;

        Log.d("init", String.format("width: %d; height: %d", width, height));

        this.mPath = new Path();
        this.mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
        this.mPath.lineTo(width, height);

        this.mPaint = new Paint();
        this.mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

        this.mPathShape = new PathShape(this.mPath, 1, 1);

        this.mShapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(this.mPathShape);
        this.mShapeDrawable.getPaint().set(this.mPaint);
        this.mShapeDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        // Doing this here because in the constructor we don't have the width and height of the view, yet
        this.init();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Log.d("onDraw", "Drawing");

        // This works, but won't let me do what I'm really trying to do
        canvas.drawLine(0.0f, 0.0f, this.getWidth() / 2.0f, this.getHeight() / 2.0f, this.mPaint);

        // This should work, but does not
        //this.mPathShape.draw(canvas, this.mPaint);

        // This should work, but does not
        //this.mShapeDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }

}
```

As you can see from my comments in the `onDraw()` method, neither using the `PathShape` nor the `ShapeDrawable` to draw the `Path` onto the `Canvas` actually works. Nothing is drawn when I try. Does anyone have any idea why?

The device I'm testing this on is running Android 4.1.1.

Comment: Just curious - have you tried creating a new Paint object inside the onDraw. I'm doing that and having success with bitmaps but wasn't sure if it was necessary or not.

Comment: I hadn't, since I didn't want to create objects in onDraw (it actually causes a warning from Lint). However, I tried it just now and got the same results. No success.

Comment: After some more investigation, and lack of response here, I think this is simply broken and I've submitted a bug report.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35229

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two issues with this.

The first is the `Paint` style. The default is `Paint.Stroke.FILL`, but with a line there's nothing to fill. I needed to add this (thanks, [Romain Guy](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35229#c1)):

```
this.mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

The second issue is that the standard height and width in the `PathShape` is not correct. I had read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/PathShape.html#PathShape%28android.graphics.Path,%20float,%20float%29) on this, but did not understand it correctly. This became apparent once I fixed the first issue. Setting it to the height and width of my custom view (since I am drawing across the whole view) fixed this. I also had to change the bounds of the `ShapeDrawable` to match.

```
this.mPathShape = new PathShape(this.mPath, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

and

```
this.mShapeDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Another issue that can cause it not to appear is if your path's dimensions are larger than your max aspect ratio, which results in warnings in your LogCat.